# Why I can't conform to a protocol with an @EnvironmentObject variable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

So I'm trying to conform to a protocol using an @EnvironmentObject variable, but the compiler complains, whereas if a use @ObservedObject it works.

Using @EnvironmentObject:

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var someOutput: String

    init(someOutput: String) {
        self.someOutput = someOutput
    }
}

protocol SomeChildView: View {
    var viewModel: ViewModel { get set }
}

struct FirstChildView: SomeChildView {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel // <-- This does not work.

    var body: some View {
        Text("")
    }
}
```

Using @ObservedObject:

```
struct FirstChildView: SomeChildView {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel // <-- Works

    var body: some View {
        Text("")
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it may be because &EnvironmentObject can not be set as these are readonly.

Comment: Thanks @PtitXav that solve the issue :)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have a class `ViewModel` in SwiftUI because the `View` struct already is a view model so you would be trying to duplicate what SwiftUI already does.

What you are probably looking for is a store object for loading/saving your model structs. Usually that object has a singleton for the app and another for previews loaded with sample data. It's usually passed into a `View` hierarchy using the `.environmentObject` modifier in the App struct and in a Preview.